# Weird Datepicker behaviour, related to blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm completly stuck with Datepicker. 
Blur hides calendar if Datepicker was active, but focus still stays in input, so I can't trigger datepicker again by clicking to input again.
Only 2 datepickers on the page works fine, all other broken this way.

This is how I set datepickers. First pair works fine, second is broken.

```
dates.intervalDatepickersSet( $( ".head-from, .head-to" ) );
dates.intervalDatepickersSet( $( ".residence-from, .residence-to" ) );
```

This is the dates.intervalDatepickersSet:

```
intervalDatepickersSet: function( el ) {
    var interval, i,
    pair = [];

    if ( el.length > 2 ) {
        var elementsContainer = el.toArray();
        for ( i in elementsContainer ) {
            if ( elementsContainer.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
                pair[0] = elementsContainer.shift();
                pair[1] = elementsContainer.shift();
                // If we are on the Update order page, we could have few elements with same classes.
                // Set datpickers for each pair of that incoming bundle of   elements.
                dates.intervalDatepickersSet( $( pair ) );
            }
        }
    }

    interval = el.datepicker({
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var prefix = dates.prefixFromTo( $( this ) ),
            option = ($(this).hasClass(prefix + '-from')) ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings);
            interval.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            /* calculations code */
    });
}
```

What is wrong with this?

**UPD**
First working pair of elements:

```
<input id="id03" class="disable text from head-from" default="__.__._____" type="text" name="Order[z_start_date]" id="z_start_date" value="<?php if($this->getAction()->getId()=="create") echo '__.__._____'; else echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd.MM.yyyy', $model->z_start_date);?>" />
<input id="id04" class="disable text to head-to" default="__.__._____" type="text" name="Order[z_end_date]" id="z_end_date" value="<?php if($this->getAction()->getId()=="create") echo '__.__._____'; else echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('dd.MM.yyyy', $model->z_end_date);?>" />
```

Second broken pair:

```
<input class="text dateOfSettlement1 residence-from" type="text" name="<?php echo $model->getAttrName($block, 'in'); ?>" value="Дата начала" default="Дата начала" />
<input class="text dateOfEviction1 residence-to" type="text" name="<?php echo $model->getAttrName($block, 'out'); ?>" value="Окончание" default="Окончание" />
```

**UPD2**

I can trigger datepicker again only when i clicked to another input or drag some element (trigger another action). What can be the reason of that behaviour?

So I can only trigger datepicker again after "focusout" event, but not after "blur". Though, calendar hides on blur.

Comment: please share html and css of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the datepicker `showOn` option. [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOn)

You probably want to set it to "both".  By default it is set to "focus" which won't trigger again if the input element still has focus.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this 'both' meanse show datepicker 'on focus' and 'on button click', thats not my case